# Reading from a CSV file to a label in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, csv, xamarin.forms

I have read a tutorial [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp), but I still cannot figure out how to successfully read a line from a CSV to appear on a label. I have created a CsvFileReader class as the tutorial suggests, but I do not know how to use it to read a line from a CSV and paste it onto a label.

```
Label label = new Label
{
    // Text = the 5th column of the 1st row of 'my_file.csv'
    VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    FontSize = 25,
    TextColor = Color.Black,
    HeightRequest = 80
};
```

Comment: Do you not know how to set text on a label or how to get the 5th column of the first row in the file?

Comment: How to get the 5th column of the first row in the file. I know simply setting text would be ```Text = "Some string"```

Comment: `var myArray = line.Split(',') will give you an array of each column. The fifth column would be `myArray[4]`. You will do this after the declaration of label, when you execute the file reading code, so it's like `label.Text = myArray[4];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `CsvHelper` to read the csv data. Install `CsvHelper` from NuGet Package.

Create a .csv file and put it into Xamarin.Forms project.

**.csv file data:** I wrote the data into excel and save as .csv file. No comma in the Excel datatable.

```
ID,Name,Age
1,A,11
2,B,12
3,C,13
4,D,14
5,E,15
```

**Set the Build Action as `Embedded resource`.**

[image]

**Create a structure for the .csv file.**

```
public class test
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Read from the .csv file.**

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
        var list = new List<test>();
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "XamarinDemo.test.csv";

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            //string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

            if (reader != null)
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                {
                    while (csv.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new test
                        {
                            ID = csv.GetField<string>(0),
                            Name = csv.GetField<string>(1),
                            Age = csv.GetField<string>(2)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        label.Text = (list.ToArray())[5].ID;  //used to get the value of ID column,6th row(the row include the column[ID, Name, Age] row.).        

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there someway to trigger the reading of the CSV besides a button click? When the page is opened, I want the text to already appear on the label

Comment: Also, I am getting an argument null exception for ```using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))```. The value ```stream``` is null.

Comment: Put the code in your page Initialize method or override the OnApearing. Have you check your file path? `XamarinDemo.test.csv`: `XamarinDemo` is the project name. `test.csv` is the file name. I put the `test.csv` in the Xamarin.Forms project named `XamarinDemo`. Create the file with the screenshot of the .csv file.

Comment: If you still have this issue, i could upload my project.

Comment: Yes, the CSV path is MyProject (name of Solution) -> MyProject.Shared -> BehindFolder -> first.csv, so ```var resourceName = "MyProject.MyProject.Shared.BehindFolder.first.csv"```. I also tried ```MyProject.Shared.BehindFolder.first.csv``` and ```BehindFolder.first.csv```, and it didn't work. I did make sure to set it as an embedded resource. I tried it with a different CSV, and it didn't work either. If it helps, the page path is MyProject -> MyProject.Shared -> UI -> page.cs. It would be great if you could upload your project. Thanks so much.

Comment: You could download the source file the github. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/ReadFromExcel